как удалить media group в чат боте
async def p_6(callback_data: CallbackQuery, bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_chat_action(callback_data.from_user.id, ChatAction.TYPING)
    await callback_data.message.delete()
    media = [
        InputMediaPhoto(media="https://123", caption=None),
        InputMediaPhoto(media="https://1234"),
        InputMediaPhoto(media="https://12345"),
    ]
    await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=callback_data.from_user.id, media=media)
    await callback_data.message.answer(text='ваше действие:', reply_markup=markup6)

Нужно удалить эту медиа группу с вызовом следующего колбэка в чате пользователя. Не могу найти простого способа. Если кто-то знает, плиз хелп.
